# Display video directly from an MTP device in Windows

Tags: windows, video-player

I'm looking for software that will display video directly from the MTP device, directly from the device I mean the software does not copy the file to the local disk as a temporary file.

I would like to have as many software names as possible.

Any software that is suitable for Windows XP and above is right for me.

Comment: Are you really Google? If not, would you mind changing your username/avatar to something not trademarked? :-) Cheers!